# Ruby on Rails: Dropzone js, getting [object Object], but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I'm getting [object Object] on my thumbnails (the background image is the area where you can click on to upload photos... I'm not sure how to load up the normal box similar to the example in http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

[image]

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>

  <div class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-square" id="mydrop">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message=""></div>
    <div id="bi_previews"></div>
    <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.file_field :beautiful_image %></div>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
  $('div#mydrop').dropzone 
    url: '/projects'
    previewsContainer: "#bi_previews"
    headers: "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    paramName: "project[beautiful_image]"
    init: ->
      @on 'success', (file, json) ->
      @on 'addedfile', (file) ->
      @on 'drop', (file) ->
        alert 'file'
        return
      return
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :projects
```

**controller**

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id, :beautiful_image, :title_name, :remove_project_images_files, project_images_files: [],
    project_images_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :photo, :_destroy]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

**model**

```
has_attached_file :beautiful_image, :styles => { :large => "800x800>", :medium => "500x500>", :thumb => "150x150#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :beautiful_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

---

## EDIT

Posting controller per comment requets

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @gear = Gear.new
  @project.gears.build
  @project.project_images.build
end

def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've checked the site; there's only one example at the top. I think it is not configured with thumbnail.. where's the example u see?

Comment: @songyy what do you mean? There's a 'Try It Out' section. Upload any image and you'll see thumbnails populate

Comment: after upload I can see a thumbnail, but here's nothing popup when I hover onto the thumbnail image. Is there anything I missed out?

Comment: @songyy yeah because that example is working fine. My issue here is that my images are returning [object Object] and not uploading correctly

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite get.. isn't the thumbnail image shown..? I.e., I can see 3 blocks of images, I assume it is the background image?

Comment: @songyy Yes, the thumbnails are showing, but its not uploading correctly. For some reason, the thumbnail (when hovered) displays errors, and in my case, its displaying [object Object].

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's javascript console when you attempt the upload?

Comment: @hellomello can you please post the controller code as well?
I also faced same issue some week ago

Comment: @bipashant hi, I added controller

Comment: @MusannifZahir naw, just that object object error in the thumbnail when I hover over it

Comment: Can you include `project_params` method?

Comment: Sorry, I've been changing the params, but everything should be project, instead of trip. I modified this for stackoverflow purposes only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rails You can't post data without using form. Rails verifies the CSRF token for each request unless `token_authentication` is turned off.In your code, you initialized `dropzone` using `div ID`. So server can't verify your `authenticity token`.

> The ApplicationController called protect_from_forgery, as appropriate. All of the controllers inherited from ApplicationController, and it appeared that there were no CSRF vulnerabilities. Through dynamic analysis, however, I discovered that the application was, in fact, vulnerable to CSRF.

So initialize your dropzone using id of the form.

HTML code

```
<%= simple_form_for @project, class: 'dropzone', id: 'project-form' do |f| %>
            <div class="fallback">
              <%= f.file_field :beautiful_image, multiple: true %>
            </div>
 <% end %>
```

and your Javascript should like this

```
   var objDropZone;
   Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
   $("#project-form").dropzone({
            acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png',
            maxFilesize: 5, //In MB
            maxFiles: 5,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function (file) {
                if (file.xhr.responseText.length > 0) {
                    var fileId = JSON.parse(file.xhr.responseText).id;
                        $.ajax({
                        url: '/projects/' + fileId,
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                           console.log('file deleted successfully');
                            var _ref;
                            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;

                        },
                        error: function () {
                          console.log('error occured while deleteing files');
                        }

                    });
                }

            },
            init: function () {
                objDropZone = this;

                this.on("success", function (file, message) {
                    console.log('file uploaded successfully')
                });

                this.on("error", function (file, message) {
                    var _ref;
                    return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
                });
             }
        });
```

Comment: I'm getting like a `POST http://localhost:3000/projects 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Comment: Are you using nested form?
It is the issue of dropzone you can't use in nested form because dropzone directly submit its own form while we choose the image

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/27206296/ruby-on-rails-image-upload-with-dropzone-in-nested-form

Comment: Now, when I try to upload images, it just disappears right away, and I get this error now: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`.

Comment: @hellomello are you using  nestedform?
or please post the server log

Comment: No, stripped everything bare so my field is not nested. But I don't get where the records are saved, if its not nested? `:beautiful_image` is a column within the `project` model. So if there's multiple images, how does it save in that record? Also, when I'm testing this, in my log, I get `Unpermitted parameter: beautiful_image`, also, it doen't store anything... all the parameters are getting `""`, empty strings.

Comment: @hellomello I wonder how can you save multiple images on a single column. also you have  project_images_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :photo, :_destroy]) on your project_params.

Comment: I have a `ProjectImages` model, and a regular `Project` model that has `beautiful_images` as a column. So I was just asking how saving images work without nested fields? Because don't you need nested fields to save multiple files so a project can be related to multiple images based on (ie: `project_id`)

Comment: Yes, You're right. Then why you need beautiful_images as column in project.
You can directly achieve it from @project.project_images.